# How to Call webservices using Jquery+Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, web-services

I am having problem with my Jquery+ajax call that will consume one of my web service method via cross domain. i have been trying all the possible way to accomplish but still no success. please help me with what i am doing wrong. may be i need to configure web server for some security settings? below is my code. please let me know if you have any question regarding with my code.

I added this in web.config of my web service.

```
    <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

and this to my application

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://si-cb01:10000/service1.asmx/GetJsonData',
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", // change data type to jsonp
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
                Result = response.d;
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

IE Console showed this error

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Google Chrome Console showed this error .

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://si-cb01:10000/service1.asmx/GetJsonData.
>       Here si-cb01 is nothing but system name with IP 192.168.*.***
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   Origin 'http://localhost:xxx' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 500.

I looked up the problem and it seems to be a Missing Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS),but I cannot understand the solution for this.

Comment: I had this issue in the past and the solution came from adding to my TOMCAT server a small piece of XML that relaxed the restriction. The error is from the fact that (apparently) your application is running in one domain while you are approaching a server in a different domain. Must confess, it took me quite a while to overcome this issue.

Comment: Is the domain of the web service server same as web server?

Comment: FYI: `CORS` policy also applies when the ports differ, even if the domain is the same, which means calling `http://domain:123/` from `http://domain:789/` also requires the `CORS` to be set.

Comment: Hii  already my code includes all the functionality you explained in web.config thoughit is showing same error.as i said before when i put jsonp it is through error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Area you sure you put the mentioned config at the right place? It should be placed inside the `web.config` of the server application, no the client application. Using `JSONP` will not work by default, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: ya i am sure.! as u explained it is  placed inside the web.config of the server application

Comment: xxxmatko,can i use IP address at url in ajax call

Comment: Yes you can use the IP address. When you look at the network tab of the browser, do you still see two requests? First with OPTION verb, and second with POST? What is the response to the first one?

Comment: with in my network tab i couldn't find any thing its empty

Comment: Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET

Comment: `GET`? In your example you are using `POST`. Try to change your javascript code to use `GET`, in order to eliminate the possibility that now your method has problem with the right verb.

Comment: checked with get but no results

Comment: Did you get any further?

Comment: Noo there are no results tried in all possible couldn't find any solution xxxmatko

Answer (score 2):

To enable CORS on IIS add the following to the web.config file of your server application:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Just for explanation, when you are calling some service which is hosted on different domain (other than your application), browser sends preflight request (request with http `OPTION` verb instead of `POST` or `GET`) and it waits for the answer. The answer, which comes from the server, means whether the server can respond to the client request or not, according to the `CORS` policy. You can use `JSONP` only if the service can responds with `JSONP`, in that case the response is wrapped something like this:

```
jsonp_callback(<YOUR JSON>)
```

where `jsonp_callback` is global function which is used to get the `JSON` and to send it to the ajax callback function.

To find more about how to enable `CORS` visit this site http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is because your ASMX service is not configured to serve requests from other domains for security reasons. All you need is to add this in `web.config` of your web service.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Please note that this will allow all websites to access your webservice. If you want only a specific site to access your web service, change the custom header like this

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://example-site.com" />
```

This will give you a detailed idea on CORS: http://enable-cors.org/

P.S: Please refrain from using `success` and `error` callbacks while using `$.ajax` as they are deprecated.

> **Deprecation Notice**: The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use
>   `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

**Update**: Try setting these too.

In web.config

```
<location path="service1.asmx">
    <system.web>
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <clear />
                <add name="HttpGet" />
                <add name="HttpPost" />
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Decorate your method like this

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpPost = true)]
public string GetJsonData()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Hii naveen already my code includes all the functionality you explained in web.config thoughit is showing same error.as i said before when i put jsonp it is through error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: CORS wont be an issue if the web config is set. Which IIS Server are you using? JSON request will be fine. No need for jsonp here.

Comment: IIS7 we are using. and again made slight modification according to u r explanation above in web.cong and found no result

Comment: are you sure that the path is as said by @xxxmatko like this? http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html. Try running a simple request if the json is complicated

Comment: naveen ya   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />is added but no result same issue as explained above